# Why is AngularFire Seed giving <Object> has no method '$changePassword'?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm starting a project from scratch using the latest angularfire seed. Everything is set up using a fresh firebase, the user test@test.com, with test123. So the user was created and login went great, bindings seem to work, etc. The angularfire annotated source seems to show that auth should have the [changePassword](http://angularfire.com/src/angularFire.html#section-63) method but throwing `console.log($scope.auth)` in the LoginCtrl's login callback confirms bleh:

```
Object
$createUser: function () { [native code] }
$login: function () { [native code] }
$logout: function () { [native code] }
error: null
user: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Make sure you grab the latest version of angularfire from github. It has fixed this bug. The CDN doesn't appear to have the latest version.

Comment: Good catch. I assumed the cdn 050 was the same as the documented 050.